# Capybara is checkbox checked?

Tags: selenium, cucumber, capybara

In the following HTML Code I am in a row that contains 4 columns: `read`, `create`, `edit` and `delete` (twice for cities and projects).

What I would like to do is to check if the read button is checked in projects. I am very new in capybara, I tried `find('citites')` then I don't know how to mention its children to check if create is checked.
Your help will be very much appreciated.

```html
<tr>
  <th class="labelCol" scope="row">Cities</th>
  <td class="dataCol col02">
    <table class="crudTable">
      <tbody>
        <tr class="crudTable">
          <td class="crudCol">
            <img src="/img/checkbox_checked.gif" alt="Checked" width="21" height="16" class="checkImg" id="crudRead___01Ib0000000118kEAA" title="Checked">
          </td>
          <td class="crudCol">
            <img src="/img/checkbox_unchecked.gif" alt="Not Checked" width="21" height="16" class="checkImg" id="crudCreate___01Ib0000000118kEAA" title="Not Checked">
          </td>
          <td class="crudCol">
            <img src="/img/checkbox_unchecked.gif" alt="Not Checked" width="21" height="16" class="checkImg" id="crudUpdate___01Ib0000000118kEAA" title="Not Checked">
          </td>
          <td class="crudCol">
            <img src="/img/checkbox_unchecked.gif" alt="Not Checked" width="21" height="16" class="checkImg" id="crudDelete___01Ib0000000118kEAA" title="Not Checked">
          </td>
          <td class="marvarCol">
            <img src="/img/checkbox_unchecked.gif" alt="Not Checked" width="21" height="16" class="checkImg" id="crudViewAll___01Ib0000000118kEAA" title="Not Checked">
          </td>
          <td class="marvarCol">
            <img src="/img/checkbox_unchecked.gif" alt="Not Checked" width="21" height="16" class="checkImg" id="crudModifyAll___01Ib0000000118kEAA" title="Not Checked">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </td>
  <th class="labelCol" scope="row">Projects</th>
  <td class="dataCol">
    <table class="crudTable">
      <tbody>
        <tr class="crudTable">
          <td class="crudCol">
            <img src="/img/checkbox_checked.gif" alt="Checked" width="21" height="16" class="checkImg" id="crudRead___01Ib00000001HDjEAM" title="Checked">
          </td>
          <td class="crudCol">
            <img src="/img/checkbox_checked.gif" alt="Checked" width="21" height="16" class="checkImg" id="crudCreate___01Ib00000001HDjEAM" title="Checked">
          </td>
          <td class="crudCol">
            <img src="/img/checkbox_checked.gif" alt="Checked" width="21" height="16" class="checkImg" id="crudUpdate___01Ib00000001HDjEAM" title="Checked">
          </td>
          <td class="crudCol">
            <img src="/img/checkbox_unchecked.gif" alt="Not Checked" width="21" height="16" class="checkImg" id="crudDelete___01Ib00000001HDjEAM" title="Not Checked">
          </td>
          <td class="marvarCol">
            <img src="/img/checkbox_unchecked.gif" alt="Not Checked" width="21" height="16" class="checkImg" id="crudViewAll___01Ib00000001HDjEAM" title="Not Checked">
          </td>
            <td class="marvarCol"><img src="/img/checkbox_unchecked.gif" alt="Not Checked" width="21" height="16" class="checkImg" id="crudModifyAll___01Ib00000001HDjEAM" title="Not Checked">
          </td>
        </tr>
```

[image]

Comment: Is the checkbox actually a checkbox? Based on the html, it looks like it is just an image.

Answer (score 6):

Your code shows obviously that your checkboxes are images.

If you had real checkboxes you could use those capybara methods to test if your checkboxes are checked or not :

[has_checked_field](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Matchers#has_checked_field?-instance_method) or [has_no_check_field](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Matchers#has_no_checked_field?-instance_method)

Answer (score 1):

`expect(page).to have_checked_field("my_check_name")`

Link to doc: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara%2FRSpecMatchers%3Ahave_checked_field

Answer (score 0):

This one work for me

```
assert page.has_checked_field?('your_checkbox_id')
```

Answer (score -1):

You can improve this with page.should have_xpath command:

```
page.should have_xpath('//table[@class='crudTable'][2]//td[@class='crudCol'][1]/img[@alt='Checked']')
```